# Django: Suggestion for models design

Tags: python, django

I need help with creating models for my simple Django app.

The purpose of the application is to let users (referees) register for matches, then admin will choose 2 users (referees) from the list of registered for given match. Right now my Matches model looks like below:

```
class Match(models.Model):

    match_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=10
    )
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='home_team'
    )
    away_team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='away_team'
    )
    match_category = models.ForeignKey(
        MatchCategory,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now
    )
    notes = models.TextField(
        max_length=1000,
        blank=True
    )
```

What I thought to do is to create new Model named MatchRegister where I will be saving match_id and user_id, something like below:

```
class MatchRegister(models.Model):
    match_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Match
    )
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Users
    )
```

And than admin will have list of registered user for given match from which he will choose two, so I thought to modify my Match model like this (add two new Fields):

```
class Match(models.Model):

    match_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=10
    )
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='home_team'
    )
    away_team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='away_team'
    )
    match_category = models.ForeignKey(
        MatchCategory,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now
    )
    notes = models.TextField(
        max_length=1000,
        blank=True
    )
    ref_a = models.ForeignKey(
        Users,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='ref_a'
    )

    ref_b = models.ForeignKey(
        Users,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='ref_b'
    )
```

This is my solution but I don't know if it is done in proper way so I want to ask you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for certain that matches will only ever have two refs, then what you propose is just fine. However, if there's an opportunity in the future for the number to change (only one, or perhaps three), an alternative would be to add a flag to the intermediate table:

```
class MatchRegister(models.Model):
    match_id = models.ForeignKey(Match)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(Users)
    chosen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

You would need business logic to constrain the number of "chosen" refs to the number you anticipate. This option makes it easy to increase or decrease the number of refs without adding or removing columns (just change the business logic).